# Function to Right Shift 2D Array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, 2d, shift

I wrote Function to Shift left in 2D array but i have problems About Right Shifting.

my left shift function looks like this

```
void left_rotate(int Array[][Column])
{
    int *flat = (int *)Array;
    int temp = flat[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < Row*Column; ++i)
        flat[i - 1] = flat[i];

    flat[Row*Column - 1] = temp;
}
```

Please Help me to shift Elements Right

Comment: First of all your code has some strange design choices that mess with readability. Second, I assume that you want to shift position of all elements in array one space to the right and to loop back so that the rightmost element is the new leftmost element, correct?

Comment: Yes you are correct, in my code Row and Column are defined Top as 3 and 6

Comment: Well then you don't need anything fancy. Simply feed the function your entire matrix (2d) array. Create new (empty) matrix with correct size inside of your function and store elements of first matrix in it using simple for loop. Just one small thing. Embed an if-statement inside the loop so that it checks if it reached last element of a row. If you don't do that you will get out-of-bounds exception.